# java applet won't run on windows 8 samsung tablet

Tags: java, windows-8, applet, tablet

I can't get an applet on a web page to run on Windows 8 Samsung Tablet.

Initially when I go to the applet it said java wasn't installed even though we installed it.
I reinstalled java v7.25, 32 bit version. Command prompt verified this.

I tried, but it wouldn't let me install 64 bit version.

After java reinstall the web page with applet no longer says java not installed but it still doesn't work at all.  It essentially just does nothing and is unresponsive.

What is the secret to getting applets running on windows 8 tablet?
thanks

***NEW INFORMATION
It appears that with java update v7.25 the java version check no longer works correctly.  This seems to be the problem.

Comment: Check your browser security settings?

Comment: Well I allowed java, is there something else?

Comment: *"What is the secret to getting applets running on windows 8 tablet?"*  Have you got it to run on *any* other configuration?   Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.

Comment: is it a windows RT tablet?

Comment: As far as I know this is the full version of Windows 8, not windows RT.  It is the Samsung ATIV Smart PC.  We are running it in desktop mode.

Comment: Andrew- I have the java applet running on various windows 8 PCs, but this is the first tablet I have encountered.  I am doing my best to get information and test but I am working with a customer remotely so I am slightly limited

Comment: Excuse me, it is a Samsung XE500T1C which claims to run full windows 8.

Comment: It appears that with java update v7.25 the java version check no longer works correctly in jnlp.  This seems to be the problem.  THANKS